# pm2 - How can I get/access process status programmatically?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am trying to write a simple server that can communicate the status of processes. I understand how i can use the pm2 package and send that data as a response. Essentially, I am trying to build a simple web UI to monitor a remote process.

The issue that I am having is:

- When I call `pm2.list()` or `pm2.jlist()`, the methods execute fine, and I can see the output in my pm2 log file, but the server doesnt send any data back
- When the above works, pm2 also restarts the the app, and I can see my restart count going up.

Is this possible?

Here is my app code:

```
const express = require('express');
const pm2 = require('pm2')

const app = express();
const { PORT = 3000 } = process.env;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('foo');
  pm2.describe((process, err) => {
    res.send(process)
  })
});


app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

pm2 json file

```
{
  "name": "testPm2app",
  "script": "1.js",
  "watch": true,
  "ignore_watch": "node_modules"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `pm2.describe` is incorrect. The first parameter should be the process name or the ID of the process. You can attach a callback function to the second parameter that will be executed with process data. Look into the below code.

```
const express = require('express');
const pm2 = require('pm2')

const app = express();
const { PORT = 3000 } = process.env;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('foo');
  pm2.describe('testPm2app', (err, data) => {
    if(err) {
        res.status(500).end();
    }
    res.send(data);
  })
});


app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```